# How to use grep on dictionary-like file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, sh, journal

Here is the output of journald via `journalctl -o verbose` . 
I was trying to narrow it down and filter only desired values.

```
   Fr 2016-12-02 18:54:33.675283 CET [s=asd;i=4;b=asdasd;m=asdasd;t=asdasd;x=asdasda]
        PRIORITY=6
        _BOOT_ID=5asd
        _MACHINE_ID=3asd
        _HOSTNAME=asd
        _SOURCE_MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP=0
        _TRANSPORT=kernel
        SYSLOG_FACILITY=0
        SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=kernel
        MESSAGE=Iasdasadt
        _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/system.slice/systemd-journald.service
        _SYSTEMD_UNIT=systemd-journald.service
```

When I apply something like -*after I dump results into a .txt*-

```
egrep -in -o --color '_SYSTEMD_UNIT=[^\n]*' /JOURNALD/verbose.txt
```

It returns;

> _SYSTEMD_UNIT=systemd-jour

Instead of;

> _SYSTEMD_UNIT=systemd-journald.service

I believe I am absolutely missing a fundamental point. However, I was unable to find it up until now. Do not hesitate to share your ideas.

Comment: I do not see why people are down-voting instead of saying something.

Comment: Are you trying to get everything until the next linebreak with `[^\n]*`?

Comment: Yes, it tried to read the whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` in your regular expression doesn't match newlines; it's matching the "n" in "journald." (`[^\n]` is matching anything but a literal `\` or `n` character here.) You should instead use `.*$`, which matches any sequence of characters up to the end of the line:

`egrep -in -o --color '_SYSTEMD_UNIT=.*$' /JOURNALD/verbose.txt`

Comment: Thank you! I put it into my code snippet and it solved my problems.